# Azure Angular ERROR in error TS6053: File 'C:/Users/<username>/projects/angular-soap-test/src/src/main.ts' not found

Tags: angular, azure

I have an angular project that runs fine on my local Windows machine but fails when I move it to an Azure Windows VM. Somehow an extra /src is being added.  The angular.json file has not changed.  Here is the relevant snippet:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "demo": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/demo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
...
```

I've tried removing the src/ in front of main.ts and polyfills.ts but then a new error says it cant find them.

I've found a [link1](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30802) and [link2](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/240), but neither of them helped.  Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

Differences running locally vs on Azure VM.
You'd think copying identical code from local Windows machine to Azure Windows VM would work fine, but you'd be wrong!

Azure Angular

> ERROR in error TS6053: File
> 'C:/Users/username/projects/angular-soap-test/src/src/main.ts' not
> found ERROR in error TS6053: File
> 'C:/Users/username/projects/angular-soap-test/src/src/polyfills.ts'
> not found

Notice how it added an extra /src
You need to go into **tsconfig.app.json** and change the files section to:

```
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
```

Next you'll get error:

> ERROR in src/app/hello.component.ts:9:12 - error TS2564: Property
> 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the
> constructor.

To fix that, go into tsconfig.json again and add the line
**"strictPropertyInitialization": false,**
In the angularCompilerOptions section.

Next you'll get many of errors similar to this:

> ERROR in src/app/soap.service.ts:43:13 - error TS7006: Parameter 'xml'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.

To fix that, go into tsconfig.json and the line
**"noImplicitAny": false,**

Now after finally fixing these problems, I see the following warning:

> Your global Angular CLI version (12.2.3) is greater than your local
> version (9.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.

I used the standard:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

But maybe it installs the wrong version on an Azure Windows VM